# Почему recyclerView выводит только один объект

Tags: android, recyclerview

RecyclerView выводит только один элемент, хотя их больше.

класс адаптера

```
    public class ContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Article> articles;// TODO: нужно получать отсортированный list
    private Context context;
    private String TAG = "contentActivity";

    public ContentAdapter(List<Article> articles, Context context) {
        this.articles = articles;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public class ArticleListHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView textView;

        public ArticleListHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contentAdapterTextView);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ArticleListHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.content_adapter_view, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Article article = articles.get(position);
        ((ArticleListHolder) holder).textView.setText(article.getFullTitle());
        ((ArticleListHolder) holder).textView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ArticleActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Article.ORDER_NUMBER, article.getOrderNumber());
            context.startActivity(intent);
            });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return articles.size();
    }
}
```

класс активити

```
public class ContentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_content);

    RecyclerView recView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.contentRecView);
    recView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recView.setAdapter(new ContentAdapter(new LinkedList<Article>(((MyApplication)getApplication()).getArticles().values()),this));


    Button menuButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.contentMenuButton);

    menuButton.setOnClickListener(view -> startActivity(new Intent(this, ContentActivity.class)));
}
}
```

ContentAdapterView.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/contentAdapterTextView"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

activity_content.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="ru.ckdigital.guideforpokemongo.ContentActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/contentMenuButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="menu"/>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/menuButton"
    android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/contentRecView"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Прокручивать пробовали список? У вас в разметке для элемента height=match_parent, он растянет каждый элемент на весь экран. Попробуйте изменить на wrap_content.

Comment: покажите как добавляете элементы. надо понять обновляется ли RecyclerView

Comment: @dramf, проблема решена, Юра правильно подсказал, все моя невнимательность))